# linq multiple field search

Tags: c#, linq

I have EF Employee table with fields EmpNo, FirstName, LastName, Email. And to create LINQ to search all columns and return existing record. If one or more fields is null or empty the return result based on existing data. I wrote code:

```
    public static int Search(EmployeeDt emp)
    {
        using (EF.Model1 context = new EF.Model1)
        {
            List<string> employee = context.Employees.Where(a => (a.EmpNo == null || a.EmpNo == emp.EmpNo)
             && (b => (b.FirstName == null || b.FirstName == emp.FirstName)
             && (c => (c.LastName == null || c.LastName == emp.LastName)).ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

But code which I tried to write isn't correct. How to write LINQ for my case?

Thanks.

Comment: Something didn't come through when you tried to `enter code here`.  Perhaps you were trying to insert an image, though keep in mind you should include your code as plain text.

Comment: Just try to use `return results.Where(a => 
      (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_dataType) && a.Data_Type == __dataType)
      ||
      (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_medium) && a.Medium == _medium)
      //other conditions
      ).ToList();`

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You can't repeat the `a =>` part of the expression, just keep the  `Where(a => ...` one. Furthermore there should always be the same number of open and close parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reuse `a=>` in second condition and compare `emp.FirstName` with null not `a` variable, change your code to

```
 List<string> employee = context.Employees.Where(a => (emp.FirstName == null || a.FirstName == emp.FirstName)  
&& (emp.LastName == null || a.LastName == emp.LastName) 
&& (emp.EmpNo == null || a.EmpNo == emp.EmpNo)).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Hien. Thanks for reply.
I tried to use your correction. It gives red wave line just in first EMP with message:
The name emp does not exist in the current context